# Facebook API: Parse FB.api response with jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Following code is returning `null` statuses.

```
FB.api("/me/statuses", function(response){
                console.log(response); 
                var statuses = $.parseJSON(response.data[0]);
                console.log(statuses);
            });
```

But response object look like:

```
Object {data: Array[25], paging: Object}
data: Array[25]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object
14: Object
15: Object
16: Object
17: Object
18: Object
19: Object
20: Object
21: Object
22: Object
23: Object
24: Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` is not a JSON string. Facebook SDK already parsed that to an Object.

So you can use `response.data` without any parsing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/